# Python linear programming - scheduling optimisation constraint on consecutive night shifts

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, schedule, pulp

I am trying to write a program to schedule a team of 8 individuals into shifts.

I want to know how to model that every individual must get **at least one night shift break for each individual**, **must not work two consecutive shifts**, and we want to ensure as **close to equal numbers of night shifts and total shifts for each individual** as possible.

I have written a demo programme in PuLP below, but would be keen to know if anyone had thoughts in any python package (`scipy`, `gurobi` etc.)

More specifically I have the following problem:

- 8 Individuals
- 3 Shifts per day (morning, afternoon, night)
- 18 Days

I want to distribute individuals to shifts to meet the following criteria:

1. There must be 3 people on each shift
2. Every individual must work 1 shift per day
3. Every individual must not work more than 2 shifts per day
4. Every individual must get at least one night shift break, preferably two
5. We should distribute these shifts as evenly as possible, especially night shifts but also the total number of shifts.
6. Each individual must not work consecutive shifts (e.g. the night shift on Day 1 and the morning shift on Day 2)

I need to know how to either write these as constraints (`.addConstraint()`) or otherwise, to include them in an objective function.

As an objective function: I have considered minimising the maximum difference in the number of night shifts, or else, minimising the maximum difference in the total number of shifts. But I don't know how to code this into PuLP. Any help would be much appreciated!

```py
## TODO: HOW TO ENCODE THE NUMBER OF RESTS FROM NIGHT SHIFT >= 1

## TODO: HOW TO ENCODE NO CONSECUTIVE SHIFTS
```

I have written the following code for my program:

```py
import itertools
import pulp.value
from pulp import LpProblem
from pulp import LpVariable, LpBinary, LpMinimize
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict 
import pandas as pd
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype

# Data
N_DAYS = 5
all_people = ["clinton", "tommy", "callum", "bonface", "rose", "dennis", "geoffrey", "sebastian"]
all_shifts = ["morning", "afternoon", "night"]
all_days = np.arange(N_DAYS)
index = np.array(list(itertools.product(all_days, all_shifts, all_people)))
df = pd.DataFrame(index, columns=["day", "shift", "person"])

# Create the Variable (LpVariable: LpBinary) that the Solver can change
to_assign = {
    (day, shift, person): LpVariable(f"{person} on day {day} {shift}", cat=LpBinary)
    for day in all_days
    for shift in all_shifts
    for person in all_people
}

# Initialise the Problem
allocation_model = LpProblem("Allocation", LpMinimize)
## TODO: HOW TO ENCODE THE MINIMISATION FUNCTION?

# Add Constraints
## TODO: HOW TO ENCODE THE NUMBER OF RESTS FROM NIGHT SHIFT >= 1
## TODO: HOW TO ENCODE NO CONSECUTIVE SHIFTS

# add people constraints
# assign each person to max 2 shifts per day
for day in all_days:
    for person in all_people:
        allocation_model.addConstraint(
            sum(to_assign[(day, shift, person)] for shift in all_shifts) <= 2
        )
# assign each person to minimum 1 shift per day
for day in all_days:
    for person in all_people:
        allocation_model.addConstraint(
            sum(to_assign[(day, shift, person)] for shift in all_shifts) == 1
        )

#  add shift constraints
# assign all shifts to three people
for day in all_days:
    for shift in all_shifts:
        allocation_model.addConstraint(
            sum(to_assign[(day, shift, person)] for person in all_people) == 3
        )

# Solve and get results:
#  solve
solver = None
allocation_model.solve()

if allocation_model.status == 1:
    print("Solution Found.")


results = defaultdict(list)
for (day, shift, person), assigned in sorted(to_assign.items()):
    if pulp.value(assigned):
        # print(f"Day {day}: Assign {person} to {shift}")
        results["day"].append(day)
        results["person"].append(person)
        results["shift"].append(shift)

df = pd.DataFrame(results)
cat_type = CategoricalDtype(categories=["morning", "afternoon", "night"], ordered=True)
df = df.astype({"shift": cat_type})
df = df.sort_values(["day", "shift"])

# print solution
print("Calendar Assignment")
print("-" * 50)
print(df)

# test equity of solution
print()
print(f"How many shifts for each individual? \n{'-'*50}\n", df.groupby("person").count()["shift"])
print()
print(f"How many days does each individual work? \n{'-'*50}\n", df.groupby("person").nunique()["day"])
print()
print(f"How many night shifts per individual? \n{'-'*50}\n", df.loc[df["shift"] == "night"].groupby("person").count()["shift"])
```

**My programme currently does not meet criteria 4. 5. or 6.**.

Comment: This is more a question of modelling rather than programming, so you might have better chances of getting an answer on [OR](https://or.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: If there was a way to solve it more easily in Scipy i'd also be super keen to hear!

Comment: Scipy.optimize doesn't provide any methods for solving mixed-integer problems. So you're on the right track with PuLP. Focus first on the mathematical modelling of the constraints.